# Moving JSS App to JSS-SXA Site

Tags: jss, sxa-jss

I have implemented Jss App in sitecore 10 instance, and now I need to move the the jss app to jss-sxa site to have the sxa structure, so what I do I have moved my items to the jss-sxa site as below

[image]

and i have disabled the app config this one

[image]

and I have added the site settings here
[image]

but when try to open in page under the moved site it gives me 404 error with this message

"Node render engine project directory does not exist. Ensure your JavaScript code has been deployed and that the configured path is correct."

any ideas, what is missing??, why this error happen even i have the dist folder in my instance root??

Answer (score 2):

On `Settings` item, you need to make sure that

1. The field `App Name` has the proper application name which is your JSS App name.
2. The field `Filesystem path` has the proper path to your JSS App. For example, `/dist/app`.
3. The field `Server side rendering engine` should be `NodeJs`.

Moreover, make sure that your JSS App files have been deployed to your Sitecore instance root directory.

Comment: Worth noting that `Server side rendering engine` can also be `http` if the rendering application is running on Next.js